# Inno Setup to fill ComboBox from PHP page with UTF-8 data

Tags: php, unicode, inno-setup

For the ComboBox, I set onchange handler `OnChange := @RegionOnChange` and I define it as follow:

```
procedure RegionOnChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
begin
  try
    WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
    WinHttpReq.Open('GET', '{#MyDomain}get_school.php?region=' + Regions.Strings[RegionComboBox.ItemIndex], false);
    WinHttpReq.Send();
    if WinHttpReq.Status = 200 then
    begin
      MsgBox(WinHttpReq.ResponseText, mbError, MB_OK)
    end;
  except
    MsgBox('error', mbError, MB_OK)
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that the returned data is `UTF-8` and Inno Setup (even though I use the `Unicode` version) doesn't display it right in the message box.

[image]

I also tried to convert the data to `UTF-16` from PHP with

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE//IGNORE', "здравейте");
```

but will no success.

**EDIT**: I tried to use `MultiByteToWideChar`. With my test string "здравейте", `WideLen` is set to 18 which seems correct but the second call doesn't copy anything in `Result`. It remains empty.

```
function 
MultiByteToWideChar(CodePage: UINT; dwFlags: DWORD; const
                             lpMultiByteStr: AnsiString; 
                             cchMultiByte: Integer; 
                             lpWideCharStr: String; 
                             cchWideChar: Integer): Integer;
external 'MultiByteToWideChar@kernel32.dll stdcall';

const
  CP_UTF8 = 65001;

function Utf8ToUtf16(const S: AnsiString): String;
var
  WideLen: Integer;
begin
  WideLen := MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, S, Length(S), Result, 0);
  Result := StringOfChar(#0, WideLen);
  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, S, Length(S), Result, WideLen);
end;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no built-in function for decoding UTF-8 string at this time... Although `MultiByteToWideChar` function could help. I'll be right back :-)

Comment: @TLama, thanks but how to call `MultiByteToWideChar` from withing `Inno Setup`?

Comment: Strange. You're doing it certainly right. You should only `SetLength` for the `Result` to be in length of `WideLen` before the second call. But even then I can't get the correct result...

Comment: I'm starting to suspect a default `AnsiString` type. In Delphi, the `AnsiString` type has the ANSI codepage and all strings passed to a variable of this type are converted this way. There is a special type of `AnsiString` type, so called [`RawByteString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.RawByteString), which doesn't perform any code page conversion, and which is btw. used as an input for functions like the one for UTF-8 decoding in Delphi. Unfortunately, there's no way to define such type in InnoSetup...

Comment: You need to make the assignment to Result *after* the first call to `MultiByteToWideChar`.  Otherwise you're writing to a zero-length buffer, which does Bad Things™.

Comment: @Miral, even if you use a fix for those Bad Things™ as I suggested two comments above, you'll still get a wrong result. I really think that it's caused by a code page conversion of the `AnsiString` default type. Unfortunately there's no way to define `AnsiString($ffff)` type (the `RawByteString` in Delphi) in InnoSetup.

Comment: @TLama, hmm, this is very discouraging. So I can't use `MultiByteToWideChar` but why sending the data as `UTF-16LE` doesn't work also?

Comment: @Miral, I screwed in the copy/paste. Of course I first get the number of required chars because initializing the string. I fixed it in the question now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That's what I'd like to answer you. But I don't know. The response you're getting in the worst possible data type, in `Variant`, which you must use here of course, but you can't typecast it to a specific type (there's no `VarAsType` function published in InnoSetup), so it's just an undebuggable internal typecasting blackbox.

Comment: Documentation for eg. [LoadStringFromFile](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_loadstringfromfile.htm) implies that it's supposed to be binary-safe, and thus should be free from string conversions.  (I've used it for binary data in the past, but only in the ANSI version of Inno.)  The problem might be in extracting the response from the Variant.  But back to the original problem; I don't know how to do it with WinHTTP but you should be able to add the [Accept-Charset](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.2) header to the request to force Unicode transfer.